# Integrating $e^{e^{ix}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{e^{ix}}dx$.

Attempt:
$e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$, so we can write
$$e^{e^{ix}}=e^{\cos{x}}e^{i\sin{x}}$$ and then use the same identity to get
$$e^{\cos{x}}(\cos{\sin{x}}+i\sin{\sin{x}})$$
but this seems impossible to integrate. Alternatively, we could try substituting $z=e^{ix}$ but then it seems that both bounds of integration are $1$.

Comment: Do you know any complex analysis?

Comment: This is a question from my complex analysis class.

Comment: There is probably some identity that makes this problem trivial, unfortunately I probably do not have enough experience to see it.

Comment: According to [wolfram alpha](http://bit.ly/1gSQiWk), the answer is $2\pi$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you substitute $z = e^{ix}$, the integral becomes an integral over the unit circle.

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}\,dx = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} e^z \frac{dz}{iz}.$$

Cauchy's integral formula makes the evaluation of that integral very easy.

Comment: Yes, this gives the correct answer. I foolishly believed that the substitution gave the bound from 1 to 1, instead of the integral around $|z|=1$. Now using Cauchy's formula, we get $2\pi e^0=\int e^{z}/i dz=2\pi$

Answer (score 5):

It might be worth pointing out that you don't have to use complex analysis for this (although I'm sure in your class that's what they are expecting). Use the power series for $e^y$ for $y = e^{ix}$ and you have that
$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}\,dx = \int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {e^{inx} \over n!}\,dx$$
The $n!$ in the denominator ensures that we can exchange integration and summation so that this is equal to
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {1 \over n!} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{inx} \, dx$$
Only the $n = 0$ term integrates to a nonzero value, so the result is just $2\pi$.

Comment: This is a creative solution! It is probably not the expected one, but I love problems that can be solved in multiple ways.

Comment: [No comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GC5E8ie2pdM&t=64).

Comment: Do we not need complex analysis to assign meaning to $e^z$ for complex $z$? Or to compute $e^{i2n\pi}$ for each integral?

Comment: Well, it depends what you call complex analysis. Integrating $e^{inx}$ requires no complex analysis (the definition of the integral of a complex-valued function involves no analysis), just breaking into real and imaginary parts then integrating sine and cosine. $e^z$ is defined through plugging $z$ into a power series... even though that involves a complex variable I don't consider this rising to the level of complex analysis.